# How to change background color of group header row in angular slickgrid?

Tags: angular9, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

[grouping in slickgrid] need to apply different background color to group header row.
There is no specific css class for it...I have tried everything please suggest some solution

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mAI0.png)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the html for the group header is:

```
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd slick-group slick-group-level-0" style="top:75px">
  <div class="slick-cell l0 r6 cell-selection">
    <span class="slick-group-toggle expanded" style="margin-left:0px"></span>
    <span class="slick-group-title" level="0">Title:  Task 1  
      <span style="color:green">(1 items)</span>
    </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

So adding some css to the 'slick-group' class should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Add random color to header row -

```
let row = document.getElementsByClassName("slick-row") as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;

for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
    row[i].style.background = this.rowColor();
}

rowColor() {
    var r = ('0' + (Math.random() * 255 | 0).toString(16)).slice(-2),
        g = ('0' + (Math.random() * 255 | 0).toString(16)).slice(-2),
        b = ('0' + (Math.random() * 255 | 0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    return '#' + r + g + b;
}
```